# Sidebar thumbnail image stretching

Tags: css, stretch

How to prevent my images from stretching on the sidebar in blogger? I've tried many different CSS for example:

```
.container {
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

The thumbnails are still stretched and I've tried the `overflow:hidden;` property as well, which works but cuts out too much of the image and I'd much rather them be resized.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-THybP4vxGMA/VpwN3LXD-jI/AAAAAAAAAcA/kpZkxwEH9P8/s1600/4afd422d987dac3041f33ffbf34f9367.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%;` to the image in order to not overflow the container. You also have to change `max-width` and `max-height` in the `#container` to `width` and `height`. Finally, you used `.container` instead of `#container`.

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
#container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-THybP4vxGMA/VpwN3LXD-jI/AAAAAAAAAcA/kpZkxwEH9P8/s1600/4afd422d987dac3041f33ffbf34f9367.jpg"/></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, however for some reason it's not changing the heigh of the image, just the width?

Comment: @hadesg See the code snippet. Width of the `img` element is 225px and height is 400px.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured a solution:

```
#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px; 
  display: block; 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
}
```